# SETI researcher finds old records of alien communication

Tags: story-identification

On another [website](http://gizmodo.com/assuming-aliens-because-why-not-i-don-t-know-which-po-1754236477) a random internet person referenced a story that they had read but didn't remember the name of. The description interested me, so hopefully someone can identify this.

> A veteran SETI technician finds some old documents buried in a safe. They show a couple of signals picked up by chance decades earler, from different stars, but with striking commonalities. Cryptographic analysis suggested the syntax was too complex for ordinary communication and thus likely a code, possibly indicating armed hostilities. The two stars were about as far apart as the closer star was to Earth. The scientist tossed the analysis in a safe, quit his job and took the key with him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the comments section of the very same website linked in your question: ["CRYPTIC", by Jack McDevitt](http://www.jackmcdevitt.com/cryptic)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I posted the question on my lunch and haven't had a chance to recheck the original thread.